# Creating C++ DLL for different languages and platforms

Tags: c++, dll, cross-platform

I want to implement some functions in C++ (create dll).
The purpose to be able to use that with different platforms like C# WinForm and Linux server with PHP for example.

What is the best way to write it once ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a plain C interface and have functions like void f(void* cpp_pointer, ...) where each cpp_pointer has a create and dispose function.